# Partition Function has got out of Synch

Tags: partitioning

we have a large database that has a number of partitioned tables
The tables are partitioned by an EventKey column  that is int datatype, with each unique value being allocate it's own partition.
For each partition we create a unique FileGroup/FileName combination.
We have a weekly job , that creates extra Partion Files/Groups in advance, and runs the ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [PartitionSchema] NEXT USED   to keep everything in sync

unfortunately , we had a schema deadlock and thinks got out of order, and we now need to fix it.
We now have 2 events mapped to the same partition, all subsequent events are mapped to a unique partition, but it is out by 1

the sql

```
SELECT 
  $PARTITION.pfPublishes(2420) as pf_2420,

  $PARTITION.pfPublishes(2421) as pf_2421,

  $PARTITION.pfPublishes(2422) as pf_2422,

  $PARTITION.pfPublishes(2423) as pf_2423,

  $PARTITION.pfPublishes(2424) as pf_2424,

  $PARTITION.pfPublishes(2425) as pf_2425
```

returns

| pf_2420 | pf_2421 | pf_2422 | pf_2423 | pf_2424 | pf_2425 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2420 | 2421 | 2422 | 2422 | 2423 | 2424 |

IE both events 2422 and 2423 are mapped to partition 2422.  All subsequent events are mapped to their own partition, but it is out by a value of 1.

What is the best way of resetting the pfPublishes  partition function to correctly map the event ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `SPLIT` on that value. You should first set the next filegroup to be used

```sql
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME partition_scheme_name NEXT USED NewFileGroup;
```

```sql
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfPublishes() SPLIT RANGE (2423);
```

Comment: Thanks - worked a treat.  Note that I moved all the data out first , and then reload it after I had done the split